# Use a comment to improve code analyst function in PyDev like ZendStudio

Tags: python, pydev, zend-studio

In Zend Studio, I can use

```
/**
@return CUser
 */
function getUser() {
}
```

to tell IDE, the type of return value of the getUser function is CUser.

but I can't do the same thing in pydev, I want to know how I can do the same thing.

Comment: Pycharm [can do this](http://forum.jetbrains.com/thread/PyCharm-748)

Comment: PyCharm is paid for, pydev is not.

Comment: Did you try something like `@returns: CUser` or `@return: CUser`, or if it has reST support `:rtype: CUser`?

Comment: is this feature in pydev's route map?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PyDev does have predefined completion modules.  It doesn't look like it works as nicely as ZendStudio, but it's similar to the feature you're looking for.

Take a look here:
http://pydev.org/manual_101_interpreter.html#PyDevInterpreterConfiguration-PredefinedCompletions

You basically define a module that acts like an interface/documentation of your module.

Comment: is this feature in pydev's route map?